# How to get an element that was created during page load?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I'm creating elements dynamically based on SQL data server side.
I want to also edit some of those element's attributes after their creation.

They way I'm trying to go about this is by generating a string with the elements and inserting it into a div's innerHTML:

```
client side:
<div id=master runat="server"></div>

server side:
string textToDiv = "<div id='" +num +"'><ul><li></li><li></li></ul></div>";
master.innerHTML = textToDiv;
```

Looks something like this in chrome:

```
<div id="master" runat="server">
  <div id='1'>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id='2'>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to change one of the child div's attributes. How do i go about doing that?

All I found on the internet is for more static uses using the method I applied when changing the 'master' div's innerHTML attribute. Is there a get() function or something similar `to document.getElementByID()` I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update and my solution:

I ended up just changing the attribute when generating the string. Used if() statements to change only the element I wanted.

Also, I moved the whole thing into a function and I'm calling the function on page load.
That way I can update the content without reloading the page.

Answer (score 2):

a better way to solve this, to just simply place your script under the html code, but still in the body, this will make sure, the script is just loaded, when everything was rendered to the screen, with this, you can instantly access the elements and you dont have to use the window.onload eventlistener

Comment: that was my first thought, but i dont know how to that because im using data taken from a sql table to create the elements.

Comment: in that case i encourage you to learn a javascript framework, because with vanilla js its very hard/complex to do, i'd choose react, with it, this would be done with very low effort, react is also not hard to learn, you should be able to get along with it within 2 hours

Comment: ill look into it. but it might not be possible for me considering the environment i work in.

Comment: so if you dont want to learn one, you can simply get the element with getElementById, or a better way is, to use document.querySelector('.element'), this function will grab the first element with the class "element" (class can be anything) and then you simply add the data to it, by defining the element.innerHTML, you can both read and change this attribute of the element

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `onload` event and then use a function for create the Element.

```
window.onload() => {
    element = document.createElement(" ");
    element.setAttribute(" ");
    element.innerHTML = ' ';
    document.getElementById(' ').appendChild(element);
}
```

I hope it's can help you

Comment: how would i go about getting the data from my sql table using this method?

Comment: Sorry I didn't know SQL but this website gives good tuto for web languages
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp